# Scheme Macro - Adding a Header to a file

Tags: header, macros, scheme

I am writing a scheme macro for a simulation tool. I create thousands of files and I want to add a header (6 lines) to each file. The code for my header runs well and the header gets created in the right way.

But the adding of the header to my file is buggy. It does not add the 6 header lines to top of my files without touching the rest, it delets the first information that are in my file. How much information is deleted, depends on the total length of header-information.

```
(let* ((out (open-input-output-file filename0) ))
            (display header out)
            (newline out)       
            (close-output-port out))
```

This is how my file looks without the header:

```
TracePro Release: 20 6 0 
Irradiance Map Data for D:****\TracePro\Aktive\sim_mod_09.oml
Linear Units in millimeters
Data for absorbing_area_focuscircle Surface 0
Data generated at 10:55:56 May 28, 2021
```

This is how my file looks with the header:

```
axle        x       y       z       a       b       c   
pyra        0       0       0       0       0       0   
lens        0       0       0       0       0       0   
coll        0       0       0       0       0       0   
mir1        0       0       0       0       0       0
glass1      0       0       0       0       0       0   
ing_area_focuscircle Surface 0
Data generated at 10:57:29 May 28, 2021
Raytrace Time: mins: 0, secs: 0*

Projected Plane Extent from surface geometry 
      TopLeft:(-1.05125,-214.755,-1.05125) 
      TopRight:(1.05125,-214.755,-1.05125)
      BottomLeft:(-1.05125,-214.755,1.05125) 
      BottomRight:(1.05125,-214.755,1.05125)
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this with Scheme?  In any case, the approach to doing this (valid on Unixy systems, may be on Windows) is: (1) open a temporary file in the same directory as the file you are processing being careful its name is unique; (2) add the header to it; (3) add the entire contents of the file you are processing to it; (3) rename it to the file you are processing.  Doing this correctly is fiddly in any language, and depending on which Scheme you are using may not be really possible.

Comment: I'd just whip up a quickie shell script instead of using scheme...

Comment: I'd create the file with enough space (6 x 80, it seems) reserved for the header from the start, in the first place; then overwrite with the header when needed. Simply put 246 pairs of `#\space` followed by `#\backspace` (or what's the proper syntax?) so it prints to terminal OK even before the header is put in. or something like that. @tfb

Comment: and by "macro" you do mean a function, right?

Comment: With macro I mean a macro for the simulation tool TracePro

Comment: @WillNess Your Idea runs well

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, especially as my knowledge of the Scheme language standards isn't good enough to even know if this is possible within a strictly-defined Scheme.  However I'll show why it's hard, and then give an example of how to solve it in Racket, first by cheating to make a probably-correct answer and then by trying to do it the hard way to make a probably-not-correct answer.

### Why it is hard

No modern filesystem I know of allows you to open a file for 'insertion' where new content is inserted into the file, pushing existing content 'down' the file.  Instead you can open a file for writing, conceptually, in two ways:

- *for appending*, which will append new content at the end;
- *for overwriting*, which will overwrite existing content with new.

(Actually these may be the same: opening for appending may just open for overwriting and then move the current location to the end of the file.)

So what you're doing in your sample is opening for overwriting, and then clobbering the content of the file with the header.

### How to do it, in outline

The way to do what you need to do, in outline, is:

1. create and open a temporary file in the same directory as the file you care about;
2. write the new content to the temporary file;
3. copy all the content of the existing file to the temporary file;
4. close the temporary file;
5. if all is well, rename the temporary file on top of the existing file, if all is *not* OK, delete it.

If you do this carefully it is safe, because file renames are atomic, or should be, in the filesystem, if the two files are in the same directory.  That means that the rename should either completely succeed or completely fail, even if the system crashes part way through or the filesystem fills or something like that.  If the filesystem doesn't garuantee that then you're pretty much stuck.

But doing it carefully is not easy (I should admit here that some of my background is doing things like this to system-critical files, so I've spent too long thinking about how to make this safe in a context where getting it wrong is very serious indeed).

### Solving this in Racket by cheating

As I said, getting the above process right is hard, and it is therefore something you often want to rely on a battle-tested library for.  [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) has such a thing: [`call-with-atomic-output-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=call-with-atomic-output-file#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._call-with-atomic-output-file%29%29).  This seems to be designed to solve exactly this problem: it deals with creating and opening the temporary file for you, deals with the renaming at the end and cleans up appropriately.  All you need is a function which copies things around.

So here is a function, `prepend-to-file` which uses `call-with-atomic-output-file` to try and do what you want.  *This is Racket-specific*, in many ways, and it is also somewhat overengineered.

```
(define (prepend-to-file file content #:buffer-size (buffer-size 40960))
  ;; prepend content to file
  ;;
  ;; Try to be a bit too clever about whether we're copying strings or bytes
  ;; based on the argument
  (let-values ([(read-it! write-it make-it)
                (if (bytes? content)
                    (values read-bytes! write-bytes make-bytes)
                    (values read-string! write-string make-string))])
    (call-with-atomic-output-file file
      (λ (out path)
        ;; out is open for writing to the temporary file, path is the
        ;; temporary file's pathname which we don't care about
        (call-with-input-file file
          (λ (in)
            ;; in is now open for reading from the real file
            (write-it content out)
            (let ([buffer (make-it buffer-size)])
              ;; copy in to out using a buffer
              (for ([nread (in-producer (thunk
                                         (read-it! buffer in))
                                        eof-object?)])
                (write-it buffer out 0 nread)))
            ;; OK just return the file for want of anything better
            file))))))
```

I think it's reasonably likely that the above code actually works in most reasonable cases.

### Solving this in Racket without cheating

If we could write `call-with-atomic-output-file` then we could solve the problem without cheating.  But getting this right is *hard*.  Here is an attempt to do this, which is *almost certainly* incorrect:

```
(define (call/temporary-output-file file proc)
  (let ([tmpname (string-append file
                                "-"
                                (number->string (random (expt 2 24))))]
        [managed #f]
        [once #t])
    ;; tmpname is the name of the temporary file: this assumes pathnames are
    ;; only strings, which is wrong.  managed is a flag which tells us if
    ;; proc returned normally, once is a flag which attempts to prevent any
    ;; continuation nasties so the whole thing can only happen once.
    (call-with-output-file tmpname
      (λ (out)
        (dynamic-wind
         (thunk
          (when (not once)
            ;; if this is the case we're getting back in, and this
            ;; is not OK
            (error 'call/temporary-output-file
                   "this is hopeless")))
         (thunk
          ;; call proc and if it returns normally note that
          (begin0 (proc out tmpname)
                  (set! managed #t)))
         (thunk
          ;; close the output port regardless
          (close-output-port out)
          (if managed
              ;; We did OK, so rename the file in place
              (rename-file-or-directory tmpname file #t)
              ;; failed, nuke the temporary file
              (when (file-exists? tmpname)
                (delete-file tmpname)))
          ;; finally set once false to prevent shenanigans
          (set! once #f)))))))
```

Notes:

- this is still Racket-specific, but it now depends only on simpler functions which have, probably, more obvious counterparts in other implementations (or in the standard);
- it *tries* to deal with some of the edge cases, but almost certainly misses some;
- it certainly does not cope in cases such as the rename failing and so on;

Again: *don't use this*: it's almost certainly buggy.

However if you did use this, then you could simply splice it in instead of `call-with-atomic-output-file` in the above code and it will, often but probably not always, work.

Comment: thank you very much. I now have enough to think about!